# How are objects treated in an anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, performance, android

Lets take this for example...

```
entryText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    TextView wordCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordCount);
    TextView charCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.charCount);

    @Override
    public synchronized void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        wordCount.setText("W: " + String.valueOf(ChosenFile.countWords(entryText.getText().toString())));
        charCount.setText("C: " + Integer.toString(entryText.getText().length()));
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Are new instances of textviews wordCount and CharCount created each time the listener is invoked? Would it be better to make them global?

How is memory handled? Lets say new instances are created, how does that affect memory?

Comment: Do the answers to [Is repeatedly instantiating an anonymous class wasteful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718353/is-repeatedly-instantiating-an-anonymous-class-wasteful) on SO answer your question?

Comment: Without knowing the implementation of `findViewById()` we cannot say for sure.

Comment: by "each time the listener is invoked", Do you mean when `addTextChangedListener` is called?  Or when `afterTextChanged` is called?

Comment: @Caleb For argument, lets say both.

Comment: For `afterTextChanged` context, @FlorianF answer bellow is correct.  For `addTextChangedListener` context, @Snowman context is correct.  It depends on if the `findViewById` creates a new instance or not.

Answer (score 3):

The variables wordCount and charCount are created and initialized only when the TextWatcher object is created and added as a listener.  No new instance is created every time the text changes.

Comment: This answer is correct. I wonder why it got downvoted.